# Using pagedown::chrome_print() in kaggle notebook

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium, chrome-web-driver, pagedown

I have been trying to use `pagedown::chrome_print('trial.html')` on a kaggle notebook but doesn't seem to work for me. first I ran into this error:

```
Error in find_chrome(): Cannot find Chromium or Google Chrome
Traceback:

1. pagedown::chrome_print("trial.html")
2. find_chrome()
3. stop("Cannot find Chromium or Google Chrome")
```

I tried installing chrome like this:

```
system("sudo apt-get install selenium")
system("sudo apt-get update")
system("sudo apt install -y chromium-chromedriver")
system("sudo cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin")
```

trying to knit again I get the error
Error in is_remote_protocol_ok(debug_port, verbose = verbose): Cannot find headless Chrome after 20 attempts
Traceback:

```
1. pagedown::chrome_print("trial.html")
2. is_remote_protocol_ok(debug_port, verbose = verbose)
3. stop("Cannot find headless Chrome after ", max_attempts, " attempts")
```

how can I set up this right, There are a couple of solutions on the internet but most of them are Python-based.

My sessionInfo

`> R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

> Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 LAPACK:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
> [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8      [5]
> LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7]
> LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   [9]
> LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11]
> LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
> datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] pagedown_0.20       lubridate_1.9.3
> forcats_1.0.0        [4] stringr_1.5.1       dplyr_1.1.4
> purrr_1.0.2          [7] readr_2.1.4         tidyr_1.3.0
> tibble_3.2.1        [10] ggplot2_3.4.4       tidyverse_2.0.0
> googlesheets4_1.1.1 [13] googledrive_2.1.1   bigrquery_1.4.2
> httr_1.4.7
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.11
> ps_1.7.5             assertthat_0.2.1      [4] digest_0.6.33
> utf8_1.2.4           IRdisplay_1.1.0.9000  [7] R6_2.5.1
> cellranger_1.1.0     repr_1.1.6.9000      [10] evaluate_0.23
> pillar_1.9.0         rlang_1.1.2          [13] curl_5.1.0
> uuid_1.1-1           mongolite_2.7.3      [16] servr_0.27
> bit_4.0.5            munsell_0.5.0        [19] compiler_4.0.5
> httpuv_1.6.12        xfun_0.41            [22] pkgconfig_2.0.3
> askpass_1.2.0        base64enc_0.1-3      [25] htmltools_0.5.7
> openssl_2.1.1        tidyselect_1.2.0     [28] fansi_1.0.5
> crayon_1.5.2         tzdb_0.4.0           [31] dbplyr_2.4.0
> withr_2.5.2          later_1.3.1          [34] grid_4.0.5
> jsonlite_1.8.8       gtable_0.3.4         [37] lifecycle_1.0.4
> DBI_1.1.3            magrittr_2.0.3       [40] scales_1.3.0
> cli_3.6.1            stringi_1.8.2        [43] promises_1.2.1
> fs_1.6.3             generics_0.1.3       [46] vctrs_0.6.5
> IRkernel_1.3.2.9000  tools_4.0.5          [49] bit64_4.0.5
> glue_1.6.2           hms_1.1.3            [52] processx_3.8.2
> fastmap_1.1.1        timechange_0.2.0     [55] colorspace_2.1-0
> gargle_1.5.2         pbdZMQ_0.3-10